# Magento 2 web configuration stuck

Tags: web-config, installation, magento2

I have a problem installing Magento 2. I set the web configuration and i click on the next button, but it is not going on the next step. I tried to set the admin url.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can try install it via comand line.

```
bin/magento setup:install --backend-frontname="adminlogin" \
--key="YOUR MAGENTO2 REPO KEY" \
--db-host="localhost" \
--db-name="DB_NAME" \
--db-user="MYSQL USERNAME" \
--db-password="PASSWORD FOR MYSQL USER" \
--language="en_US" \
--currency="USD" \
--timezone="America/New_York" \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--use-secure=0 \
--base-url="http://YOUR.DOMAIN" \
--base-url-secure="https://YOUR.DOMAIN"" \
--admin-user=adminuser \
--admin-password=admin123@ \
--admin-email=admin@newmagento.com \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=user \
--cleanup-database
```

Try it and let me see errorlog, if it doesn't worked for you.

Maybe you have troubles with server or permissions configs.